# VueJS Vuetify contents default centered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vue cli version @ 5.0.6 | Vuetify version: vuetify@2.6.7

I've used vuejs+vuetify for a little bit now and my mind is just bugging out, I'm sure all vuejs/vuetify contents aren't set to centered by default. I have created a new project and I haven't touched any formatting or theming configurations.

Here is my code for a simple login page:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-icon
      x-large
      style="font-size: 125px"
    > mdi-account </v-icon>

    <!-- login form card -->
    <v-card max-width="525px">
      <v-container>
        <v-form ref="login">
          <v-card-title>
            <h1> Login </h1>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-text-field
            label="Email"
            outlined
          />
          <v-text-field
            label="Passwrd"
            outlined
          />
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn> Login </v-btn>
        </v-form>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // 
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The icon is centered already in the page without setting any styling, and whenever I change the size of my card it resizes but shifts to the left side of the page.

[image: Page]

Comment: is this the entry level page or is it like a component used in a layout or page? if so could you provide the parent component code?

Comment: By default, `v-icon` has the `align-items: center;` css rule. So if your parent uses a column flex-box, that's why it's centered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `<div>`. You should write:

```
<v-row justify="center"></v-row>
```